# Solve $x\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals, substitution, quartics

I would like to solve the equation $x\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ analytically, without using Wolfram Alpha. I have tried several substitutions, including $x=\cos(t)$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}=t$, but they all fail and eventually result in a quartic polynomial which is not easily solved. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The [minimal polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2+%281+-+sqrt%282%29+%2B+sqrt%28-1+%2B+2+sqrt%282%29%29%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D) for the root is $x^4-2x^3+x^2+2x-1=0\implies x=\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac12\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}$.

Comment: Correct. I have of course checked the solution numerically and given the rather simple form of the solution I would expect that it should be possible to find the root(s) without Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: There is a formula for solving 4th degree equations. It takes up most of a page. You should be able to find it by searching the web for "quartic formula" or "solve fourth degree equations".

Comment: From $x^4-2x^3+x^2+2x-1=0$, maybe notice that $(x^2-x+1)^2 = x^4-2x^3+3x^2-2x+1$, so the equation is equivalent to $(x^2-x+1)^2 - 2x^2 = 0$, or $(x^2-(1+\sqrt{2})x+1)(x^2-(1-\sqrt{2})x+1) = 0$.  And then either of the factors can be solved with the quadratic equation.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes, I am aware of this formula, but I would not like to use it. My hope would be to be able to do a series of variable substitutions and end up with something solvable.

Comment: I think @Damiel has found the way. Or maybe not – somehow the $2x-1$ has become $-2x+1$, no?

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice the mismatch between $-2x+1$ in $(x^2-x+1)^2$ and $2x-1$ in the given polynomial.

Comment: Luckily, it looks like correcting that to $(x^2-x+1)^2 - 2(x-1)^2 = 0$ should salvage the factorization.

Comment: Also try $x=\frac{t+1}2$ to get $t^4-2t^2+16t+1=0$

Comment: @Daniel, many thanks for your help! This indeed works out, I had not thought about your elegant trick.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There is a way to avoid from the quartic.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Side note: We need prove that the minimal polynomial don't produce extraneous roots or we need ruled out extraneous roots.

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, of course after taking squares a couple times to get a polynomial equation you need to check for extraneous roots.  (Two of the roots of the polynomial are complex, and one of the real roots is also extraneous.)

Answer (score 2):

$$x\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
substitute $x=\sqrt{y}$
$$\sqrt y\left(1+\sqrt{1-y}\right)=\sqrt{1-y}$$
divide both sides by $\sqrt{y}$
$$1+\sqrt{1-y}=\sqrt{y^{-1}-1}$$
square both sides
$$2-y+2\sqrt{1-y}=y^{-1}-1$$
isolate the square root
$$2\sqrt{1-y}=y+y^{-1}-3$$
square both sides
$$4-4y=y^2+y^{-2}-6y-6y^{-1}+11$$
multiply both sides by $y^2$
$$4y^2-4y^3=y^4-6y^3+11y^2-6y+1$$
subtract the left hand side from the right
$$y^4-2y^3+7y^2-6y+1=0$$
Factoring $y^4-2y^3+7y^2-6y$ we get
$$y^4-2y^3+7y^2-6y=y(y^3-2y^2+7y-6)=y(y-1)(y^2-y+6)=(y^2-y)(y^2-y+6)$$
Substitute $y^2-y=z$
$$y^4-2y^3+7y^2-6y=z^2+6z$$
Plugging it back in we get
$$z^2+6z+1=0$$
$$(z+3)^2-8=0$$
$$z=-3±\sqrt{8}$$
Undoing the substitution we get
$$y^2-y+3±\sqrt{8}=0$$
$$y=\frac{-(-1)±\sqrt{(-1)^2-4(1)(3±\sqrt{8})}}{2(1)}=\frac{1±\sqrt{-11±4\sqrt{8}}}{2}$$
Knowing $x=\sqrt{y}$ we get the following
$$x=\sqrt\frac{1±\sqrt{-11±4\sqrt{8}}}{2}$$
Three of these solutions are extraneous

Comment: Presumably, three of those four numbers are extraneous. Is the remaining one the same as what @Tyma got in the comments?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, the only number that solves the OP’s equation is the following one :$$x=\sqrt\frac{1-\sqrt{-11+4\sqrt{8}}}{2}$$

Comment: @Angelo, and I believe that's the same as Tyma's $${1\over2}-{1\over\sqrt2}+(1/2)\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}$$ although it certainly looks different.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are right, it is the same number, indeed $$\begin{align}&\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac12\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}=\\&=\sqrt{\left(\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac12\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}\right)^2}=\\&=\sqrt{\left(-\frac{\sqrt2-1}2 +\frac12\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}\right)^2}=\\&=\sqrt{\frac{3-2\sqrt2}4+\frac{2\sqrt2-1}4-\frac{(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}}2}=\\&=\sqrt{\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{(3-2\sqrt2)(2\sqrt2-1)}}2}=\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{-11+8\sqrt2}}2}=\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{-11+4\sqrt8}}2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe $\sqrt {1-x^2}≥0$ implies that,  $x≥0.$

Thus, under the restriction $0≤x≤\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}$ we have:

$$\begin{align}x\sqrt{1-x^2}&=\sqrt{1-x^2}-x\\
\left(x\sqrt {1-x^2}\right)^2&=1-2x\sqrt {1-x^2}\end{align}$$

Letting $x\sqrt {1-x^2}=u$, we have:

$$\begin{align}&u^2=1-2u\\
\implies &u^2+2u-1=0\end{align}$$

This leads to:

$$\begin{align}&u=\sqrt{1-x^2}-x\\
\implies &ux=u-x^2,\,x≠0\\
\implies &x^2+ux-u=0.\end{align}$$

Finally, note that all possible roots of the original equation must satisfy the inequality $0≤x≤\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}.$

Comment: You could also observe that from the equation, $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \frac{x}{1-x}$, so $u = x\sqrt{1-x^2} = \frac{x^2}{1-x}$.  So then, $x^2 + ux - u = 0$, which gives a solution through only two successive quadratic equations instead of three.

Comment: Why must all possible roots satisfy that inequality, lone?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because, the inequality $\sqrt {1-x^2}≥x>0$ preserves equivalence between all mathematical steps.  Otherwise, extraneous roots are waiting for us at the door..$\ddot\smile$, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to provide the *trigonometric* approach as a $3$rd answer, thinking it might be useful to some readers.

---

Substitute $x=\sin\theta$, where $0\leqslant \theta\leqslant \frac {\pi}{2}$ based on the fact $x\geqslant 0$, then we have:

$$\begin{align}&\sin\theta+\sin \theta\cos \theta=\cos \theta\\
\implies &\cos \theta-\sin \theta=\sin \theta\cos \theta\\
\implies &1-\sin (2\theta)=\frac{\sin ^2 (2\theta)}{4}\end{align}$$

Since $\sin (2\theta)\geqslant 0$ we obtain:

$$\begin{align}&\sin^2(2\theta)+4\sin (2\theta)-4=0\\
\implies &\sin (2\theta)=2\sqrt 2-2\\
\implies &\theta=\frac 12\arcsin \left(2\sqrt 2-2\right)\end{align}$$

Finally, the answer is:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=\sin\left(\frac 12\arcsin \left(2\sqrt 2-2\right)\right)}$$

---

Important note:

The final answer assume that, for $0\leqslant \theta\leqslant \frac {\pi}{2}$ the inequality $\cos\theta\geqslant \sin\theta$ holds to avoid [extraneous roots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions). No other root satisfies the inequality $\cos\theta\geqslant \sin\theta$, under the restriction $0\leqslant \theta\leqslant \frac {\pi}{2}.$

Comment: Excellent proofs.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for checking the answers.

Comment: How is cos(x)-sin(x)=2(1-sin(2x))? Is this a trigonometric identity I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Another variation.

We observe that, $\sqrt {1-x^2}≥0$ and $1+\sqrt {1-x^2}>0$ imply $x≥0$.

Letting $\sqrt {1-x^2}=u,~u≥0$ we have:

$$\begin{cases}
ux=u-x\\u^2+x^2=1\end{cases}$$

Then setting $u=a+b,~ x=a-b$ under the restriction $a≥b≥0$, we have:

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}a^2-b^2=2b\\a^2+b^2=\frac 12\end{cases}\\
\implies &4b^2+4b-1=0\\
\implies &x=\frac{\sqrt {4b+1}}{2}-b.\end{align}$$

This completes the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

$$x^2\left(1+2\sqrt {1-x^2}+1-x^2\right)=1-x^2$$

$$x^2\left(2+2\sqrt {1-x^2}-x^2\right)=1-x^2$$
Substitute $x^2=y$,

$$y\left(2+2\sqrt {1-y}-y\right)=1-y$$

$$2y+2y\sqrt {1-y}-y^2=1-y$$

$$2y\sqrt {1-y}=1-y+y^2-2y$$

$$4y^2(1-y)=(y^2-3y+1)^2$$

$$y^4-2y^3+7y^2-6y+1=0$$

$$(y^2-y+3)^2=8$$

$$y^2-y+3=\pm 2\sqrt 2$$

$$y = \frac {1}{2}\bigg(1 \pm \sqrt{8 \sqrt 2 - 11}\bigg)$$

$$x=\pm\sqrt {\frac {1}{2}\bigg(1 \pm \sqrt{8 \sqrt 2 - 11}\bigg)}$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let us make the substitution $y := \sqrt{1-x^2}$; then we get the system of polynomial equations
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 & = 1, \\
x(1+y) & = y.
\end{align*}
From here, if we solve the second equation for $y$, $y = \frac{x}{1-x}$, and substitute into the first equation, it is straightforward to get the polynomial equation
$$x^4 - 2x^3  + x^2 + 2x - 1 = 0.$$
However, let us go back to the original system of two equations in $(x, y)$.  Here, the first equation is the unit circle, and the second equation is equivalent to $(x-1)(y+1) = -1$, so it is a hyperbola with center $(1, -1)$.  We see that both curves are symmetric about the line $y = -x$; therefore, if $(x, y)$ is a solution to the system of equations, then so is $(-y, -x)$.  This implies that if $\alpha$ is a root of the quartic polynomial, then so is $-\frac{\alpha}{1 - \alpha} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}$.

From here, we can hypothesize that if $K$ is the splitting field of the quartic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then there might be an element $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K / \mathbb{Q})$ which permutes the roots according to $\alpha \mapsto \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}$.  If this is the case, then it is easy to see that $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{id}$ since it fixes each root of the quartic; however $\sigma \ne \operatorname{id}$ since the only fixed point of $\alpha \mapsto \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}$ is 2, and 2 is not a root of the quartic.  Then setting $L$ to be the fixed field of $\sigma$, we will have $\operatorname{Tr}^K_L(\alpha) = \alpha + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} = \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha - 1}$.  This suggests searching for a polynomial which will have $\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha - 1}$ as a root, and hopefully finding the roots of this polynomial will be simpler because $L$ has smaller degree over $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, from this point, we fairly quickly see that
$$\left( \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha-1} \right)^2 - 2 \left( \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha-1} \right) - 1 = \frac{\alpha^4 - 2\alpha^2(\alpha-1) - (\alpha-1)^2}{(\alpha-1)^2} = \\
\frac{\alpha^4 - 2\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 2\alpha - 1}{(\alpha-1)^2} = 0.$$

But then, that means that $\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha-1} = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$.  Another application of the quadratic formula to the equation $\alpha^2 - (1 \pm \sqrt{2}) \alpha + (1\pm\sqrt{2}) = 0$ gives the roots of the quartic.  (Then from here, two of the roots of the quartic will be complex, and one of the real roots will not satisfy the original equation because it does not satisfy $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \frac{x}{1-x} \ge 0$.)